# Make table cell value red if value is >= 0

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can i make the table cell value if it's >= 0 then it makes the table rows background color red?. And by the way the value is fetched from a database.

Comment: What language is your server building the page with (ex. asp, php)?  For js solution you can use something like `var cells=document.getElementsByTagName("td");  for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){ if(cells[i].innerHTML<0)cells[i].style.backgroundColor=red;}`

Answer (score 4):

Using vanilla JS, after the edit:
([Here is a working fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/c9aWd/) ([In this one the entire row gets colored red](http://jsfiddle.net/Na4mE/))

```
window.onload = function(){ // After all the contents has loaded
    var cells=document.getElementsByTagName("td"); //select all the table cell tags
    for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){  //iterate through each of them
       //check if content is more than 0
       if(parseFloat(cells[i].textContent || cells[i].innerText)>=0){ 
           cells[i].style.backgroundColor="red"; //change background to red
       }
    }
};
```

If you only need to support modern browsers, I think [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/3p3qV/) is prettier:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("td").filter(function(elem){
        return parseFloat(elem.textContent) >= 0;
    }).forEach(function(elem){
        elem.style.backgroundColor="red";
    });
 }, false);
```

old content, jquery solution:

---

```
$(function(){  //after the dom is loaded
    $("td").each(function() {
        if(parseFloat($(this).text()) >= 0){ //for every element whose text's float value is less than 0
           $(this).css("background-color","red"); //change the background color to red
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: I guess the question is how to get value from DB and use it in JS

Comment: @mkk Since it was tagged jquery and javascript. I read it as if he was able to create the page displaying his table data, but did not know how to color the table cells whose value was less than 0. Also, I pressed enter which turned into an edit mess, thankfully Rodrigo picked up on that and fixed it

Comment: Looks like the question is for `>=` and not `<`

Comment: I'm using javascript and not jquery.

Comment: @Donald I've added a vanilla javascript solution :)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin i appreciate it. Now my problem is all of my table rows cells are getting red background color, what i want was make the background color of my table row red if for example my table cell "count" has a value of greater than 0 then the whole background color of the row becomes red.

Comment: sorry for becoming a demanding one.. I'm still a beginner in the world of coding.. and i feel inspired by this helping people..

Comment: @Donald see the updated post, in particular this: http://jsfiddle.net/Na4mE/ . I'm glad I helped, I hope you learn from this code :)

Comment: Hmmm still not sure if it's the right code. Because it makes all the background color red of all the rows because it's fetched from a database, all the values with like > 0 becomes red. What i want was a specific cell with a <td> rs.getString(5) </td> which is count.. what i want is that count if it has a value of >= 0 the row becomes red but the other rows are alternately white and gray background colors.

Comment: You say: " all the values with like > 0 becomes red.", Your question was: "Make table cell value red if value is >= 0". This is the _right_ code for what you asked to be done. If you have another question you should ask it in another question, preferably in a more specific manner. If you want other rows to alternate color - that can be done, but that's another question (which has been answered in SO before). If you want to check specifically for rs.getString(5), that's also one different question. (checking innerText or textContent directly directly).

Comment: Thank you very much benjamin. finally worked.